# Hi there, Can anyone explain about the laravel migration and model stuff

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, migration, models

So i did read laravel docs, but it does not help me much, what i actually want to do is to setup a new database and create a table and insert some data.

But the problem is i don't even know the sequence to do that. like whether to build a model first or do a migration or run migration.

kindly do help me getting this stuff. thanks

Comment: You will get much better answers in a laravel forum...

Comment: First you need to install laravel.. you can start with that. Then create your database. Then edit database.php for connection to data. Then you can continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create database in laravel
1. Create migration
    - To create a migration, use the make:migration

```
php artisan make:migration create_all_tables
```

2. Once create your migration

   - Open migration "your_project\database\migrations"
   - Create schema

> ```
>  Schema::create('preferences', function(Blueprint $table){
>     $table->increments('id');
>     $table->string('key', 50);
>     $table->text('text');
>     $table->timestamps();
>   });
> ```

```
- Your migration look like this

  <?php
  use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
  use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

  class CreateFlockTables extends Migration
  {
    public function up()
    {
      Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('user_name', 20); 
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->string('full_name', 50);         
        $table->string('contact_number', 50);
        $table->string('unit', 10);
        $table->text('address');    
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
      });

      Schema::create('preferences', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('key', 50);
        $table->text('text');
        $table->timestamps();
      });
    }

    public function down()
    {
      Schema::drop('preferences');
      Schema::drop('users');
    }
  }
```

3. Database setting (forge is just example name you can give anything)

   - In ".env" file (local setting)

> DB_HOST=localhost
>           DB_DATABASE=forge
>           DB_USERNAME=root
>           DB_PASSWORD=

```
- In "your_project\config\database.php"
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

4. Create database in phpmyadmin with name forge
5. Run migration : php artisan migrate

Comment: Thanks, please accept my answer if it was helps you...

Answer (score 0):

Whether you first create a model or a migration is entirely up to you. However, the table must exist if you want to use the model class you've created.